# Absolut value of complex function $\frac{1}{1-e^z}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Why is for $g(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}:
> $$
> |g(z)|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+e^{2 \operatorname{Re} z }(1-2 \cos (\operatorname{Im} z ))}},
> $

---

My approach:
We want to calculate $|g(z)|,$ that is
$$
\left|\frac{1}{e^z-1}\right|=\frac{1}{|e^z-1|}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(e^z-1)^2}}
$$
and
$$
(e^z-1)^2=1-2e^z+e^{2z}.
$$
We know that
$$
e^z=e^{\operatorname{Re} z +i\operatorname{Im} z }=e^{\operatorname{Re} z }e^{i\operatorname{Im} z }=e^{\operatorname{Re} z }\left[\cos(\operatorname{Im} z )+i\sin(\operatorname{Im} z )\right]
$$
and
$$
e^{2z}=(e^{\operatorname{Re} z }\left[\cos(\operatorname{Im} z )+i\sin(\operatorname{Im} z )\right])^2=e^{2\operatorname{Re} z }\left[\cos(\operatorname{Im} z )+i\sin(\operatorname{Im} z )\right]^2
$$
resulting in
$$
1-2e^z+e^{2z}=1-2e^{\operatorname{Re} z }\left[\cos(\operatorname{Im} z )+i\sin(\operatorname{Im} z )\right]+e^{2\operatorname{Re} z }\left[\cos(\operatorname{Im} z )+i\sin(\operatorname{Im} z )\right]^2
$$
I do not see how to continue from here. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The limit doesn't exist, it diverges to $+\infty $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|z + h + k\mathbf{i} | = |x + h + y\mathbf{i} + k\mathbf{i}| = \sqrt{(x + h)^2 + (y + k)^2}$

Then, $$|e^z - 1| = |e^{x}e^{y\mathbf{i}} - 1| = |e^{x}\cos y + e^x\sin y\mathbf{i} - 1|$$.

Hence, $$Re \to e^x\cos y - 1$$ $$Im \to e^x\sin y$$

Therefore, $$|e^z - 1| = \sqrt{(e^x\cos y - 1)^2 + (e^x\sin y)^2} = \sqrt{e^{2x}\cos^2 y - 2e^x\cos y + 1  + e^{2x}\sin^2 y} = \sqrt{e^{2x}\big{[}\cos^2 y + \sin^2 y\big{]}  - 2e^x\cos y + 1} = \sqrt{e^{2x} - 2e^x\cos y + 1} = \sqrt{1 + e^{Re\text{ }z}\big{[} e^{Re\text{ }z} - 2\cos{(Im\text{ }z)}\big{]}}$$

Please recheck

> $\sqrt{1 + e^{2Re\text{ }z}\big{[} 1 - 2\cos{(Im\text{ }z)}\big{]}}$

as it should be $$\sqrt{1 + e^{Re\text{ }z}\big{[} e^{Re\text{ }z} - 2\cos{(Im\text{ }z)}\big{]}}$$